# Double integration with various curves

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

$$\iint_D e^{2(x^2+y^2)}\, dxdy$$
where $D\colon\, x^2+y^2 \geq 4, x^2+y^2\leq 25, y=x, x\geq 0, y\geq0$.

I cannot understand how to solve this; please help.

Comment: Start by trying to draw the curves in the plane. If you're bad at drawing, you could try https://www.geogebra.org/graphing for example. Note that $x^2=y^2=r^2$ is a curve around the origin with radius $r$.

Comment: Convert the problem into polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, are you sure that $x=y$ is part of the region $D$? This renders the integral equal to zero, since it is a line with $\theta=\pi/4$ and $\int_{a}^{a}dx=0$.

If $x=y$ condition is gone:

The region $D$ lies in the first quadrant of the $xy$ plane between the circles with radii 2 and 5 ($x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$). After converting your problem into polar coordinates (like said by Olivier Oloa), we have

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{2}^{5}e^{2r^2}r\,dr\,d\theta.$$

We can solve this by first integrating by $r$ and then $\theta$:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{2}^{5}e^{2r^2}r\,dr\,d\theta=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\, \frac{e^{8}}{4}\left( e^{42}-1\right)d\theta=\frac{\pi e^{8}}{8}\left( e^{42}-1\right).$$

Note that the first integration by $r$ was made by substitution $u=r^2$ and $du=2r\, dr$.

Comment: Thank you for solving but I couldn't understand why the condition y=x was eliminated, please explain

Comment: @Ankita Pal Think about where the line y=x lies in the xy plane. It is found at θ=π/4 in polar coordinates. The integral in θ would thus have the same upper and lower bound of integration, meaning it would evaluate to $0$.

Comment: Ok now I understood 

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One would be tempted to make a [polar change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Change_of_variables) :
$$
x=r\cos\theta,
\\\\
y=r\sin\theta,
\\\\
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{r^2}=r\ge0
$$ with $0\le\theta \le \frac \pi2$ then you have $dxdy=r dr d\theta$.

Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Please give the full solution 